# UNIX | Conocer el tipo de archivo por medio de su extensión

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Cómo conocer el tipo de archivo del que es un archivo por medio de su extensión.

Por ejemplo:

Extensión .txt, es un archivo de tipo: Texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente el concepto de extensión no existe como lo existe en Windows, es decir, un catálogo en el registro del sistema con cada extensión. En los ambientes POSIX tales como Ubuntu, android, IOS, Solaris... lo más parecido es usar el content-type

Sintaxis:

```
file --mime-type <ruta del archivo>
```

Por ejemplo:

```
file --mime-type /etc/hosts
```

Esta utilidad valida aún cuando el archivo no tenga extensión.